# XIB Displaying SubComponent

Tags: objective-c, nsview, xib

I created a custom view, which has one button and one text field , as given below

```
@interface CommUICustomSignInView : CommUICustomView {

 IBOutlet NSButton *pBtn;
 IBOutlet NSTextField *pTextField;
 NSTrackingArea *pTrackingArea;
 NSCursor *pPonitHandCursor;
}
@property (nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet NSButton *pBtn;
@property (nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet NSTextField *pTextField;
```

All items are linked properly, with the view,

In Another window controller XIB, i have added one tab view, in one of the tab item view, i am going to add this view,
added one tab view and assigning this view as below,

```
NSTabViewItem *pTabViewItem = [pTabView tabViewItemAtIndex:0];

if(pOfflineCTlist == nil){
  pOfflineCTlist = [[CommUIOfflineCTlist alloc]         
                initWithNibName:@"CommUIOfflineViewController" bundle:nil];
}

[pTabViewItem setView : [pOfflineCTlist view]];

[pTabView selectTabViewItemAtIndex:0];
```

Now with that, i could able to track the mouse event in customSignInview, in nstrackregion, 
but i couldn't see the other controls, sign-in button and text field, 
Am i doing something wrong,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found following way to do this,

1 -- Created a Resource like Button / text field in the Main view,

2 -- Put them over the custom view,

3 -- Link them with the custom view,

now i could able to see it, 
Is there any other approach then please suggest me,